# what is wrong in this sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I had created two Tables 'tbl_book_info' and 'tbl_books' (table descriptions
are below) in MySQL Database

what should I change in my SQL query

I had used subquery inside WHERE clause.

All Records of 'tbl_books'-

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| accid | accno | status |
+-------+-------+--------+
| 10001 |   101 | I      |
| 10001 |   102 | I      |
| 10001 |   103 | A      |
| 10002 |   101 | A      |
| 10002 |   102 | A      |
| 10002 |   103 | I      |
| 10002 |   104 | I      |
| 10002 |   105 | I      |
| 10003 |   101 | A      |
| 10003 |   102 | A      |
| 10003 |   103 | A      |
| 10003 |   104 | I      |
| 10003 |   105 | I      |
| 10004 |   101 | A      |
| 10004 |   102 | I      |
| 10004 |   103 | A      |
| 10004 |   104 | A      |
| 10004 |   105 | A      |
| 10005 |   101 | A      |
| 10005 |   102 | A      |
| 10005 |   103 | A      |
| 10005 |   104 | A      |
| 10005 |   105 | A      |
+-------+-------+--------+
23 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

All Records of 'tbl_book_info'-

```
+----------+------------------+-------+-------------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
| b_acc_id | b_name           | b_qty | b_type      | b_auth1 | b_auth2 | b_pub       | b_pages | b_rack | b_price | b_about |
+----------+------------------+-------+-------------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
|    10001 | Java             |     3 | Programming | lala    | -       | kallo       |     800 |      1 |  799.00 | -       |
|    10002 | Cpp              |     5 | Programming | Kallo   | -       | Mehta group |     400 |      2 |  300.00 | -       |
|    10003 | VB.net           |     5 | Programming | lalaji  | -       | amam co.    |     479 |      3 |  100.00 | -       |
|    10004 | DBMS             |     5 | prog        | lalal   | -       | kallo       |     888 |      3 |  499.00 | -       |
|    10005 | computer network |     5 | Networking  | Mirabai | -       | kabirdas    |     789 |      2 |  800.00 | -       |
+----------+------------------+-------+-------------+---------+---------+-------------+---------+--------+---------+---------+
```

desc tbl_books;

```
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ | Field  | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+ | accid  | int(5)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       | | accno  | int(3)     | NO | PRI | 0       |       | | status | varchar(1) | YES  |     | A       |       |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

desc tbl_book_info;

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| b_acc_id | int(5)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| b_name   | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| b_qty    | int(2)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| b_type   | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| b_auth1  | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| b_auth2  | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| b_pub    | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| b_pages  | int(4)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| b_rack   | int(5)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| b_price  | decimal(6,2) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| b_about  | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here tbl_books.accid REFERS tbl_book_info.b_acc_id

My query is:

```
select b_name, b_qty, b_acc_id , (count(*)) Issued, (count(*)) Available
From tbl_book_info
where tbl_book_info.b_acc_id in (select accid from tbl_books
                                 where status = 'I'
                                 GROUP BY status) ;
```

I want to perform join between the tables 'tbl_book_info' and 'tbl_books' to print the Result as

Desired Output:

```
+--------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+
| b_name | b_qty | b_acc_id | Issued | Available |
+--------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+
| Java   |     3 |    10001 |      2 |         1 |
+--------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+
| Cpp    |     5 |    10002 |      3 |         2 |
+--------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+
```

...(and more)

Output Came:

```
+--------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+
| b_name | b_qty | b_acc_id | Issued | Available |
+--------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+
| Java   |     3 |    10001 |      4 |         4 |
+--------+-------+----------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: What's the subquery supposed to do? It's invalid, and the GROUP BY makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a Join, then you should do it, not doing a strange subquery in a where. You can do a Join and a conditional case to sum in two different columns the Issued and the Avalilables

```
Select a.b_name, a.b_qty, a.b_acc_id , sum(case 
                                        when b.status='I' then 1
                                        else 0
                                     end) as Issued,
                                     sum(case 
                                        when b.status='A' then 1
                                        else 0
                                     end) as Available
From tbl_book_info a left join tbl_books b on a.b_acc_id=b.accid
group by a.b_name, a.b_qty, a.b_acc_id
```

Comment: great :) it worked, you have used 'case' in sum() function , for what this is used

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can take a short-cut for this type of query:

```
select bi.b_name, bi.b_qty, bi.b_acc_id, 
       sum( b.status = 'I' ) as Issued,
       sum( b.status = 'A' ) as Available
from tbl_book_info bi left join
     tbl_books b 
     on bi.b_acc_id = b.accid
group by bi.b_name, bi.b_qty, bi.b_acc_id;
```

MySQL treats boolean expressions as integers in a numeric context (such as `SUM()`).  Also note that the table aliases are abbreviations for the table name.

With an index on `books(acc_id, status)`, this might be faster using a subqueries:

```
select bi.b_name, bi.b_qty, bi.b_acc_id, 
       (select count(*)
        from tbl_books b
        where b.accid = bi.b_acc_id and
              b.status = 'I'
       ) as Issued,
       (select count(*)
        from tbl_books b
        where b.accid = bi.b_acc_id and
              b.status = 'A'
       ) as Available
from tbl_book_info bi ;
```

The performance gain is by avoiding the work for the outer `group by` (typically a sort).  The index can be used instead.

Answer (score -2):

I have not tried this solution yet, but I can say that you need to do Group By `accid` column of `tbl_books` table. So please make following change in your query:

```
select b_name, b_qty, b_acc_id , (count(*)) Issued, (count(*)) Available
From tbl_book_info
where tbl_book_info.b_acc_id in (select accid from tbl_books
                                 where status = 'I'
                                 GROUP BY accid) ;
```